# Extjs 5: Tagfield vertical grow issue as a widget column

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I was putting a tagfield as a widget column inside grid panel with Extjs 5, and faced a grow issue. The field did not get vertical expand, but will bring a scroll bar inside the field.

I searched for some answer, the column's configure `cellWrap: true` could work under Ext js 6. However it could not work for 5.

I create the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hk4) for this issue, could someone help me to figure out how to resolve this problem?

Thanks very much.

Comment: In fact, it works in 5.1.3, so it is a bug in the outdated 5.1.0 version you have used in Fiddle. Which version exactly do you use in production and is it possible to update to 5.1.3? The updates should fix a ton of bugs over which you may stumble sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for your information so much. My current project is under 5.0.1. I will check the 5.1.3 source to see whether I can do some overides with it.@Alexander

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add css 
Check Fiddle: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hle